# When Outlook lists the size of an email as "5MB" does it round up?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When Outlook lists the size of an email as "5MB" does it round up so that 5MB is definitely no larger than that, or does it round to nearest whole number so that "5MB" may in fact be >5MB?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do rounding. It means nothing greater than 5*1024*1024 bytes = 5242880 bytes.